# Can I parse data in real time from web-site?

Tags: r

I need parse data from web-site and write it in dataframe, an example from https://www.24option.com/international/. Which library can help me? Is it real?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's real, you can use [rvest](https://github.com/hadley/rvest)